# How to use Linux watch against a command piping to sed

Tags: linux, sed, watch

When I perform this command:

```
ip -s link show enp65s0f0 | sed -n '/    vf 4/,$p'
```

I get this output

```
    vf 4 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, vlan 3932, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    RX: bytes  packets  mcast   bcast
    3835259656164 3452586352 1       1098
    TX: bytes  packets
    3310560630151 3007239043
```

I want to watch that command, however when I run the following:

```
watch "ip -s link show enp65s0f0 | sed -n '/    vf 4/,$p'"
```

I get this error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unexpected `,'
```

Troubleshooting:

- I tried using escape characters in my sed command like this `watch "ip -s link show enp65s0f0 | sed -n '/\ \ \ \ vf\ 4/,$p'"`, same error.
- Tried using single quotes around watch command like this `watch 'ip -s link show enp65s0f0 | sed -n '/    vf 4/,$p''`, I get the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unterminated address regex`

How can I get watch against my command piping to sed?

Comment: This might help: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to escape $ symbol

```
watch "ip -s link show enp65s0f0 | sed -n '/    vf 4/,\$p'"
```